# Flac to mp3 conversion offsets sound by a few ms

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, mp3, flac

When running this simple conversion command: `ffmpeg -i fileA.flac fileB.mp3`
, the mp3 output is offset by about 5 ms.

This does not happen if I try to convert to Vorbis/Ogg (i.e `ffmpeg -i fileA.flac fileC.ogg`)

Audacity screenshot:

[image: Audacity screenshot showing offset]

Any idea why this happens and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of how MP3 encoding (or actually, both encoding and decoding) works. See the [technical FAQ](http://lame.sourceforge.net/tech-FAQ.txt):

> Why is a decoded MP3 longer than the original .wav file?
>
> Because LAME (and all other MDCT based encoders) add padding to the
> beginning and end of each song. LAME embeds the amount of padding in the ancillary data of the first frame of the MP3 file. (LAME INFO tag).

Continuing:

> All *decoders* I have tested introduce a delay of 528 samples.  That
> is, after decoding an mp3 file, the output will have 528 samples of
> 0's appended to the front.  This is because the standard
> MDCT/filterbank routines used by the ISO have a 528 sample delay.  It
> would be possible to write a MDCT/filterbank routine with a 0 sample
> delay (see description of Takehiro's MDCT/filterbank routine used in
> LAME encoding below) but I dont know that anyone has done this.
> Furthermore, because of the overlapped nature of MDCT frames, the
> first half of the first granule (1 granule=576 samples) doesn't have a
> previous frame to overlap with, resulting in attenuation of the first
> N samples.

It gets more technical if you read on, but this should summarize the issue.

Comment: Is there a way to cut out the 528 sample delay directly through ffmpeg?

Comment: Ok, it seems like `ffmpeg -ss 0.0528 -i fileA.flac fileB.mp3` seem to do the trick, though I don't understand why, since the file uses a sample rate of 44100Hz, shouldn't 528 samples take 0.0119 seconds?

Comment: `-ss 0.0528` means there's an offset of 0.0528 seconds, not samples. But you can trim samples like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39809030/435093